# How to show/hide v-for elements in a dynamic array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'd like to show/hide each todo detail in a boxe,when corresponding `todo` button is clicked. 
In reality both `todos` and `todoDetails` are  obtained dynamically from server.

The script is like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/karlomn/xgrpp6e6/)

```
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    title: 'todos',
    seen: false,
    todos: ['eat', 'work'] ,//dynamic array  
    todoDetails: [{'eat': 'some yummy food'}, {'work': 'as hard as you can'}]
  },
  methods: {
    openbox: function() {
      seen = !seen ;
    }
  }
});
```

And the template is like:

```
<div id="demo" v-cloak>
  <h1>{{title }}</h1>

  <ul>
    <li v-for="todo in todos" @click="openBox">
      <button @click="openbox">{{ todo }}</button>
      <p v-show="seen"> More info: {{todoDetails[todo]}} </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But I can not get it to work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I update your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marconak/vr89j5bm/).

Base problem was:

- `@click="openBox"` but name of function is `@click="openbox"`
- `seen = !seen ;` add `this` keyword `this.seen = !this.seen;`

Template:

```
<div id="demo" v-cloak>
  <h1>{{title }}</h1>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="todo in todos" @click="openbox(todo)">
      <button>{{ todo.name }}</button>
      <p v-show="todo.seen"> To do details for {{todoDetails[todo.name]}} </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Vue

```
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    title: 'todos',
    seen: false,
    todos: [{
      name: 'eat',
      seen: false
    }, {
      name: 'work',
      seen: false
    }], //dynamic array  
    todoDetails: {
      'eat': 'some yummy food',
      'work': 'as hard as you can'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openbox: function(todo) {
      todo.seen = !todo.seen;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Great, thanks! please add your answer code here, as I think that's the SO requirement.